# Override ASP.NET Core appsettings key name that as dots with environment variable in a container

Tags: asp.net-core, environment-variables, containers, appsettings

I'm trying to migrate a legacy app into a new .net 6 version, the issue that I have is that this app has a 3rd party library with keys that will be looked up in the `appsettings.json` file.

Something like this(note the dots in the key):

```
{
    "one.special.key":"one value"
}
```

The issue that I'm facing now is that my new app will be running inside a container and the keys will be injected using environment variables and I don't think that containers environments (aka - linux) accept environment variables with dots, only the convention with one/double underscore like this: *one_special_key*.

How can I override an `appsetting.json` that has a key with dots in it like `some.key.with.dots=hello` instead of the traditional `some_key_without_dots=hello`?

Comment: This document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#non-prefixed-environment-variables   may help,but it would only overload the varirable share the same key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in this k8s PR:  https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/48986 the validation was made more permiss and it allows to pass dot based environment variables names.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong - if you keep an environment variable like this `one__special__key` - the application will use this value instead of the value from the `appsettings.json` file.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5002040#non-prefixed-environment-variables)

> Using the default configuration, the
> EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider loads configuration from
> environment variable key-value pairs after reading appsettings.json,
> appsettings.{Environment}.json, and user secrets. Therefore, key
> values read from the environment override values read from
> appsettings.json, appsettings.{Environment}.json, and user secrets.

Comment: thx for the link, I'm aware of the overloading priority, the issue is if the key injected with dots will be valid in a container environment and if the key-value overloading will work the same way as a key with underscores.